# Trig Identity Math Problem $\sqrt{3} \tan(3x)=1$ from $0\leq x<360$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation from $0\leq x < 360$

$\sqrt{3}\tan(3x)=1,$

I have tried to solve this equation by dividing the square root into both sides, and then making $3x$ equal to inverse $\tan$ of 1/$\sqrt{3}$. I only get $3x=30$ and $x=10$. I do not believe that this is right.

Comment: It is correct, but it is not the only solution (provided that you mean $10^\circ$).

Answer (score 1):

Just divide by $\sqrt{3}$ to get tan(3x) = 1/$\sqrt{3}$ then do $3x=tan^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})+180^{o}k$ for k=0,1,2,3... So x = 10, 70, 130,..

Comment: You can do x^{\circ} ($x^{\circ}$) for a degree symbol.

Comment: Also, don't forget negative $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = 3x$, so $0^{\circ}\leq y < 1080^{\circ}$. Then, we must have:

$$\sqrt{3}\tan(y) = 1$$

$$\tan(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Because $\tan(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ whenever $y = 30^{\circ} + n\cdot 180^{\circ}$ for any integer $n$, we find that the solutions satisfying $0^{\circ}\leq y < 1080^{\circ}$ are $y= 30^{\circ},\ 210^{\circ},\ 390^{\circ},\ 570^{\circ},\ 750^{\circ},\ 930^{\circ}$. Then, we have:

$$x = \frac{y}{3} = \boxed{10^{\circ},\ 70^{\circ},\ 130^{\circ},\ 190^{\circ},\ 250^{\circ},\ 310^{\circ}}$$

Note that the solutions all differ by $60^{\circ}$, one third the period of $\tan$.